# Jetbrains Rider filewatcher is not compiling scss to css

Tags: css, sass, rider, file-watcher

I started using Rider a few days back and I wanted to start using SCSS in my projects and compile them back to CSS, I was messing around with the File Watcher but i couldn't get it to work, I keep getting this message in my console when I turn show console to Always; Process finished with exit code 0, but i dont see any changes in my CSS file compared to my SCSS file.

In the link below you can see my File Watcher settings, I appreciate any help i get on this,

Thanks alot.

[File watcher settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuVaG.png)

This is the output of the console:

[Console ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sjFA.png)

Here is the css tree:

[Css tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umcvZ.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rider File Watcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eXIn.png)

I found the solution to my problem. For some reason, the following line was configured in 'Output paths to refresh':

```
$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
```

Obviously, this means that the file watcher will not refresh .css or .css.map files. It should be empty in order for the compiler to update the .css file.

I hope others can use this answer to continue their work in the future.

Comment: I understand the exact opposite, I understand that it will refresh if not empty. Also it's the default value. But I abandonned that file watcher thing, it's too feeble.

Comment: I am in the same situation. I wasted a lot of time trying to make it to work. I then switched back to the vs which is seamless

Comment: A tool that would probably work better for this would be Webpack instead of using file watcher, although this could be seen as going overboard for some applications

Comment: still doesn't work properly in late 2023, groannn

Comment: still doesn't work properly in early 2024, groannn